# So I've done pretty well on my code bootcamp pre-work. I just cant read this well enough to debug it. I think I'm screwed in the bootcamp

Tags: javascript

I can't read JS well enough or barely at all and I need to debug this. If I copy paste code into google I get nothing. I have been doing okay with most of the projects, but then they throw this. I hope this isn't a sign I'm in over my head... This is too much money too waste. I'm poor as it is.

Google, My text books

```
$("#factButton").on("click", function() {
var number = Math.floor((Math.random() * booFacts.length));
$("#factText").text(booFacts[number])
})  

var booFacts = ["Boo is a pomeranian, Boo's best friend is another 
pomeranian named Buddy, Boo the Pomeranian was born on March 16, making 
him a Pisces, Boo's favourite food is grass, Boo has released two books" 
};

$("#textPink").on("click", function() {
$("#funText").css("color", pink)
})

$("#textOrange").on("click", function() {
$("#funText").css("color", "orange")
})
$("#textGreen").on("click", function() {
$("#funText").css("color: "green")
})


$("#boxGrow").on(click, function() {
$("#box").animate({height:"+=35px", 
    width:"+=35px"}, "fast");
})

$("#boxShrink").on(click, function() {
$("#box").animate({height:"-=35px", width:"-=35px"}, "fast");
})

C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe --inspect-brk=7514 logic.js 
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:7514/526fd8e0-d4b7-4d23-b81d- 
62b99e284ae8
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
Debugger attached.
c:\Users\richa\Desktop\BrokenCode\logic.js:16
$("#funText").css("color: "green")
                  ^^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:721:23)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:829:12)
at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:721:23)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:829:12)
at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
```

Comment: If you paid for it, its their job to help you.

Comment: Look at the other `.css` lines and the one highlighted. All the others work, that one doesnt ... What could that be?

Comment: I agree Jonas. part of the project was to use use google and stack over flow. O think thats BS.

Comment: You forgot to close this color string while attempting to add css `$("#funText").css("color: "green")`

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#funText").css("color: "green")
                  ^^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

It shows you where is the error. It is a typo.

You have working example
`$("#funText").css("color", "orange")`
And broken highlighted
`$("#funText").css("color: "green")`

Could you find the difference?